# About Web Design and building

Tags: php, html

I want to build a new website I found a programmer that build it for me.
He going to do it with php, he say that first I need to design the website
so now i looking for web design...
My question is what do I need to send to the programmer that he can start is work.
After the Designer is Finishing
What the designer should make
Template, code, file
How to connect between the two

Comment: If your designer and programmer cannot figure that out together, they should be replaced.

Comment: Give them first what your requirements.Or set a meeting so both you can discuss what's about your project.To come up with the design etch...

Comment: I'm looking for freelance Web designer

Answer (score 2):

The designers will create the template in PSD format and programmers will convert the PSD file into HTML code. This will enable programmers to convert all the designs into the HTML code. You have to send the content of the site to the programmers while all the designs are created by designers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the programmer will need the design in HTML. Most designers do their initial design work in Adobe Photoshop and then slice their design and create HTML code with it.

Some programmers may be willing to make the HTML from the slices (Your designer should know what that means).

The programmer should be able to take the design and create multiple pages from it.

Comment: Thanks so much for quick response You say that the product should be HTML page That's what I need to get from the designer

Comment: I'm looking for freelance Web designer

Answer (score 0):

The designer will/should work with you to create a vision for what your site will look like.  He/she will do the following:

**Design**:

- Create a sitemap.  What pages will be on your site?
- Create wireframes.  This will show how the pages will look structurally, but without images and content.
- Create a few home page design concepts and work with you to choose what fits your business best.
- Design the web pages as PSD files.  http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/psd
- Cut images from the PSD so that they are the right size/dimension for the programmer.

Once the design is complete, the programmer can begin building out the site in PHP/HTML/JavaScript/CSS based on the PSD

- The programmer will then make templates, using PHP or a templating engine, and code the site by reusing components, such as the header, footer, navigation, and other common element.

This is not a solid requirement or flow.  Many designers will do some coding.  Some designers will do all the coding.  Some programmers will do some image cutting.  It really depends on the scope and complexity of the project, as well as the skills of the individuals involved.

It's easier to find expert-level people who specialize in one thing, but there are experts out there who can share job responsibilities.

No matter what, good communication between you, the programmer, and the designer is important so that each person has a clear understanding of their role, as well as what the deliverables are.

Comment: I'm looking for freelance Web designer

Comment: @yaniv - If you're looking for a freelance web designer, check out http://odesk.com or http://freelancer.com